# AMD HCC Swizzle Intrinsic

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpgpu, gpu

I've just recently discovered AMD's equivalent to CUDA's __byte_perm intrinsic; `amdgcn_ds_swizzle`(Or at least I think its the equivalent of a byte permutation function). My problem is this: CUDA's byte perm takes in two unsigned 32 bit integers, and then permutes that based on the value of the selector argument (supplied as a hex value). However, AMD's swizzle function only takes in one single unsigned 32 bit integer, and one int that's named as "pattern". How do I utilize AMD's Swizzle intrinsic function?

Comment: have you read the manual?

Comment: [This](http://scchan.github.io/hcc/hc_8hpp.html) is the only manual I have of it. It doesn't give much information. I have already searched all over the internet and haven't found anything unfortunately (Unless I'm looking in the wrong place). So I have turned to stackoverflow as my last resort.

Comment: http://gpuopen.com/amd-gcn-assembly-cross-lane-operations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ds_swizzle** and **__byte_perm** do are a little bit different.  One permutes a whole register across lanes and the later permutes any four bytes from two 32-bit regs.

AMD's [ds_swizzle_b32](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_GCN3_Instruction_Set_Architecture_rev1.1.pdf) GCN instruction is actually swapping values with other lanes. You specify the 32-bit register in the lane you want to read and the 32-bit register you want to place it in. There is also a hard-coded value that specifies how these are to be swapped. A great explanation of ds_swizzle_b32 is [here](http://gpuopen.com/amd-gcn-assembly-cross-lane-operations/) as user3528438 pointed out.

The [__byte_perm](http://datamining.xmu.edu.cn/documentation/cuda4.1/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_g0b8b8156fe619205bf8d65acd8f29131.html) does not swap data with other lanes.  It just gathers any 4 bytes from two 32-bit registers in its own lane and stores it to a register. There is no cross-lane traffic.

I'm guessing the next question would be how to do a "byte permute" on AMD GCN hardware. The instruction for that is **v_perm_b32**. (see page 12-152 [here](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_GCN3_Instruction_Set_Architecture_rev1.1.pdf)) It basically selects any four bytes from two specified 32-bit registers.

Comment: Thank you for this information. The v_perm_b32 function doesn't seem to have been implemented with the HCC compiler. Is there a way to implement it manually using the raw assembly instruction? I was thinking about calling the "v_perm_b32" instruction inside the device code using the "asm" function, but apparently this is illegal with HCC.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about the HCC compiler because it has no Windows Visual Studio support. I know its possible in C# (__asm4GCN) but that is probably not what you are looking for.  It would be awesome if HCC or OpenCL supported inline asm!  By the way, maybe you can request that v_perm_b32 support be added to the HCC compiler. (or even better asm support)